# Linq to XML select descendent of descendant each with specific attribute

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have found many articles on getting a descendant with a specific attribute, but I can't seem to find anything on selecting multiple descendants with different attributes with LINQ to XML. So from the following example, I need to select all the Grandchildren where `Parent name = Ken AND Child name = Lorna`. Potentially, I need to have up to 4 `AND` clauses as my real XML is deeper than the example below.

I can code selecting all children of `Ken`, but can't find an example to go deeper than that.

Any help is greatly appreciated

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FamilyTree>
  <Parent name="Ken">
    <Child name="Lorna">
      <Grandchild name="Andrew"/>
      <Grandchild name="Brian"/>
    </Child>
    <Child name="Mike">
      <Grandchild name="Ann"/>
      <Grandchild name="Beth"/>
    </Child>
  </Parent>
  <Parent name="Norma">
    <Child name="Owen">
      <Grandchild name="Charles"/>
    </Child>
    <Child name="Peter">
      <Grandchild name="Charlotte"/>
    </Child>
  </Parent>
  <Parent name="Quinn">
    <Child name="Robert">
      <Grandchild name="Debbie"/>
      <Grandchild name="Eric"/>
    </Child>
    <Child name="Susan">
      <Grandchild name="Frank"/>
    </Child>
  </Parent>
</FamilyTree>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple options here, but I'd suggest the simplest thing is just to check each Grandchild:

```
var grandchildren = doc
    .Descendants("Grandchild")
    .Where(x => (string) x.Parent.Parent.Attribute("name") == "Ken" &&
                (string) x.Parent.Attribute("name") == "Lorna");
```

Or you could find all the relevant `Child` elements and then retrieves their children:

```
var grandchildren = doc
    .Descendants("Child")
    .Where(x => (string) x.Parent.Attribute("name") == "Ken" &&
                (string) x.Attribute("name") == "Lorna")
    .Elements("Grandchild");
```